# What is the good way to represent a list of choices for a combo box or list box in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, listbox

Is there anything more compact (or otherwise better) than this?

```
    <x:Array x:Key="titles" Type="System:String">
        <System:String>Mr.</System:String>
        <System:String>Mrs.</System:String>
        <System:String>Ms.</System:String>
    </x:Array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code that's the most consice you can AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Lookups">
      <x:XData>
        <ComboBoxItems xmlns="">
          <Salutations>
            <Item>Mr.</Item>
            <Item>Mrs.</Item>
            <Item>Ms.</Item>
          </Salutations>
          <States>
            <Item>AL</Item>
            <Item>AK</Item>
            <Item>CA</Item>
            <Item>CT</Item>
          </States>
          <Wizards>
            <Item>Gandalf</Item>
            <Item>Radagast</Item>
            <Item>Pallando</Item>
            <Item>Saruman</Item>
          </Wizards>
        </ComboBoxItems>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
  </Page.Resources>
  <StackPanel>  
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Lookups}, XPath=ComboBoxItems/Salutations/*}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Lookups}, XPath=ComboBoxItems/States/*}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Lookups}, XPath=ComboBoxItems/Wizards/*}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

An advantage of this approach is that you can maintain the items completely separately from the XAML if you need to - you can store them in an external XML document and load the `XmlDataProvider` at run time if you need to.